# Cannot Connect to Google Memorystore (Redis)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

After creating a new Google Memorystore of type Redis Standard, I'm allocated an internal IP address of 10.0.0.#. However, none of my compute instances in the project can access it (telnet fails).

Also unable to access it via the Cloud Shell.

Comment: Are your compute instances in the same region and using the same network? (I assume so, but I thought I would throw that out there just in case).

Comment: Different region, same network (default). Is it not possible to do cross region?

Comment: From the documentation: "You can connect to the Redis instance from any Compute Engine VM instance located within the same project, region and network as the Redis instance." I don't see anything to suggest cross-region is possible.

Comment: @Zack, your comment is fitting to be a good answer. Can you post it as the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/connect-redis-instance-gce): "You can connect to the Redis instance from any Compute Engine VM instance located within the same project, region and network as the Redis instance." I don't see anything to suggest that cross-region is possible.